# Error displaying Fabric Wallets: EACCES: permission denied, open '${Private key path}'

Tags: npm, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ibm-blockchain, ibp-vscode-extension

While working on IBM Blockchain Platform vs code extension,

after connecting to default local fabric network, some of the users of wallets don't load properly.

Their Attributes are "none" and extension gives the error at the title.

Two of them are "admin" users of orderer and org1. What may be the problem here?

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhoKJ.png)

Comment: Have you tried tearing down the network and restarting it to see if that solves the problem ? If not then I suggest you raise an issue here providing as much detail as possible about your environment including operating system extension version etc
https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/blockchain-vscode-extension/issues

Comment: https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/blockchain-vscode-extension/issues/2156

This issue's gone with the next patch on ibp vs code extension. I managed to build this example at local. Thanks for the help!
https://github.com/IBM/evote/blob/master/docs/run-local.md